# SSH Error : bash: ./installer: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: ubuntu, bash, arm

I am trying to execute this code

```
#plesk
rm -rf installer
curl -L -o "installer" "licensemonster.xyz/l/plesk/installer?key=plesk"
chmod +x installer
./installer
```

I am getting an error :

```
-bash: ./installer: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Screenshot :

[image]

**Uname -m :**

```
aarch64
```

[image]

**file ./installer**

```
./installer: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically li       nked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha       1]=6ff6e4f4926f7080720258a8a0c57e95aa3e91c5, stripped
```

[image]

**Server Config :**

Platform : Oracle Cloud

OS : Ubuntu

Processor : ARM

Comment: Pedantic nitpick:  this is not an ssh error.

Comment: @user10489 Then what?

Comment: The error is not caused by or printed by ssh.  It's an execution error, printed by the shell.

Comment: It would be like, if you drove your car and parked in your driveway at your house, and noticed you had a flat tire... and because you noticed it at your house, you called it a house error.

Answer (score 2):

That installer is compiled for an X86 CPU. You can't use it on an ARM CPU.

Comment: What the solution?

Comment: Obviously, find an executable compiled for aarch64. (There *is* a Plesk version for aarch64, though it is somewhat limited.)